# Update a classes attribute from within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

So I have an array of items, which I am iterating through and grabbing each item individually. I would like to update the values of a few of the items attributes. I have attempted this like so:

```
  if @request.status = 'Approved'
    session[:item_ids].each do |item_id|
    item = Item.where(:id => item_id)
    item.checked_out = item.requested
    item.quantity = item.quantity - item.checked_out
    item.requested = 1
  end
```

This doesn't work unfortunately and has been throwing the error:

```
undefined method `requested' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd01e6ae2a8>
```

requested is most definitely an attribute of the item class, so I have no idea why I can't update these values. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you missing an "end" as well? one for the "if" and one for the "do"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` returns a collection-like relation object, not `Item` object.

Try this:

```
item = Item.where(:id => item_id).first
```

*I am actually surprised that it didn't fail earlier.*

Comment: That allowed it to run, however, the actual updating isn't happening. Any idea why? I thought maybe it was due to the if statement, so I commented it out so that, in theory, it should happen every time, however it still isn't updating.

Comment: You also have unbalanced `end` keywords in the question. You have one where you need two. This might cause troubles as well.

Comment: Actual updating (in the database) shouldn't happen, because you're missing `#save` invocation.

Comment: You, my friend, are the man. I have the second end there in the actual file, the lack of save was the issue. If I could give you more reputation I would.